# Keras Permute Layer vs Reshape Layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

Both model1 and model2 below have output shape (None, 64, 10).  Do model1 and model2 behave exactly the same?  If no, how are their behaviors different?  If yes, why do we need Permute layer when Reshape layer can do every thing Permute layer does?

```
model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(Permute((2, 1), input_shape=(10, 64)))

model2 = Sequential()
model2.add(Reshape((64, 10), input_shape=(10, 64)))
```

model2.add(Reshape((64, 10), input_shape=(10, 64)))

Answer (score 1):

you can test it by your own...

```
model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(Permute((2, 1), input_shape=(10, 64)))

model2 = Sequential()
model2.add(Reshape((64, 10), input_shape=(10, 64)))

X = np.random.uniform(0,1, (3,10,64))
tf.reduce_all(model1(X) == model2(X)) # ===> False
```

Permute is different from Reshape. Permute is simply changing elements on the axis while Reshape is like reordering the elements after you flattened them

```
model3 = Sequential()
model3.add(Flatten(input_shape=(10, 64)))
model3.add(Reshape((64, 10)))

tf.reduce_all(model2(X) == model3(X)) # ===> True
```